# How to use order_by in Django queryset?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I apply order_by to a queryset and the results are mixed up.
Is there any difference if I apply it to a queryset?

The table has three columns: Name Age Description
Here is the code:

```
Query = table1.objects.filter(Name__iexact='Nico').order_by('Age').distinct()
ages = Query.values_list('Age')
descr= Query.values_list('Description')
```

Here only Age is sorted correctly. The match between these Age and Description is distorted. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong ? Well, actually, the design itself. "Parallel lists" - two lists (or similar types) matched on position - is an antipattern. It's bulky, harder to use (you have to keep track of indexes and subscript the two lists), and brittle (if anything changes one of the lists for whatever reason, the data are not matched anymore).

If you need to keep both informations matched, keep them in a single list (or here queryset) as tuples (here `query.values_list("Age", "Description")`) or dicts (here `query.values("Age", "Description"))`. This will make your code simpler and safer.

*NB: I of course assume you want to match those two querysets given your mention that "The match between these Age and Description is distorted".*

Comment: thanks. I thought this is similar to SQL, when used SQL all columns match isnt it?

Comment: This __IS__ SQL (undef the hood). But [querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy) - nothing is executed before you start accessing the queryset's content - so with your current code you are actually doing TWO db queries. And not all RDBMS support sorting on a field that's not part of the query FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

Try to have your `order_by` on the end after distinct.

Either that or try

```
Query = table1.objects.filter(Name__iexact='Nico').distinct()

Query = Query.order_by('Age')
```